# Graph API - You do not have permission to create an unpublished post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post something using the Graph API, but I want to make this post "invisible" in my page (actually my company page), so I can use it o only for sponsored posts.

I tried to use "is_hidden", "privacy - SELF" or "published".

In the first option nothing changed.

The second doens't work for pages, only profiles.

And the third, that would be the bestone, give me an error: "You do not have permission to create an unpublished post".

Anyone know how can I get this permission? I already gave all the permissions to the token that I am using.

Or anyone knows another way to create "invisible" posts for my page?

This is the code I am using (here i changed my page ID for "me", because I can`t say what is my company's page).

```
<?php


session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );



use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('530349683736101','my_password');

$session = new FacebookSession('[REMOVED ACCESS TOKEN]');


    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      '/me/feed',
      array (
        'message' => 'This is a test message',
        //'is_hidden' => 'true',
        'published' => 'false',
        //'privacy' => '{value: "SELF"}',
      )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token in your example was a user access token and `/me` for a user access token refers to the current user

Users can't create unpublished posts, those must be created on Pages and should be created using a [Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) retrieved on behalf of an admin of the page

Comment: BTW i strongly recommend removing that app from your privacy settings and reauthorising it as you included a real access token in your question

Comment: Did it! Thank you for the answer and the recommedation!